# How to set up outbound emails for matching bounces?

Tags: email, email-bounces

I am creating a system for sending out notification emails. Each email is pulled from a database table. I have full control over the outbound email programatically. This system, if possible, should be able to mark these outbound emails for bounces.

What is the best way to send out an email so as to be able to link the most bounced emails back to the original outbound email? I have components that allows me to pull emails from the return mailbox so that I can get access to headers and body of the bounces. I know how to detect various bounce "types", but not sure on proven ways to match bounce to original outbound email.

One idea is to include an X-header, say "x-email-id", with intent to parse it out. Is this reliable?